# App enfine flexible with way more readiness and liveness requests than expected

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I deployed a simple nodejs server on Google app engine flex.
When it has 1 instance running, it is getting 3 times as much liveness and readyness checks as it should be reiceving considering the configuration on my app.yml file.

[image: app engine console]

The documentation says:
`If you examine the nginx.health_check logs for your application, you might see health check polling happening more frequently than you have configured, due to the redundant health checkers that are also following your settings. These redundant health checkers are created automatically and you cannot configure them.`

Still this does look like an aggressive behaviour. Is this normal?

My app.yml config :

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: web

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 3
  disk_size_gb: 10

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.6

readiness_check:
  path: "/readiness_check"
  timeout_sec: 4
  check_interval_sec: 5
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 1
  app_start_timeout_sec: 300

liveness_check:
  path: "/liveness_check"
  timeout_sec: 4
  check_interval_sec: 30
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. Three different locations are checking health of your service. You have configured the health check to be every five seconds. If you want less health check traffic, change `check_interval_sec: 5` to be a larger number.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer! Do you know about the three locations from the documentation?

Comment: @httpete The documentation for HTTP(S) Load Balancers details the regions where health checks are performed from. I do not know 100% that they are the same for GAE Flexible but Flex runs on Compute Engine instances, so I am assuming so.